# Using variables/parameters as a trigger in Azure Devops pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to use a variable name for my trigger, like this:

```
 parameters:
- name: releaseName 
  type: string 
  default: develop
trigger:
  - ${{ parameters.releaseName }}

 ... rest of pipeline...
```

Or like this:

```
variables:
  releaseName : develop
trigger:
  - ${{ variables.releaseName }}

... rest of pipeline...
```

But apparently this won't work because the variables are evaluated at runtime. By "won't work" I mean that either I get a warning "A template expression is not allowed in this context" or the pipeline simply isn't being triggered, depending on the syntax I use to access the variable.

Is there another way of defining a "variable" so that I can make this work?

The reason I want to do this is that in my complete pipeline I want to reference the variable many times, not just in the trigger. Hardcoding this value and manually replacing it when needed, for example by copy-pasting it into notepad++, do a search and replace, and paste it back in the YAML file works fine for now. But it would be great if all I had to do was go into Azure and change one value, and my whole pipeline file is changed.

Comment: can you not suffice with a ‘*’ trigger and then just use the variable in all other places than the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way of defining a "variable" so that I can make this work?

I am afraid that Azure DevOps doesn't support defining the variable/parameter in the trigger field.

Refer to this doc: [Yaml Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#triggers)

> Trigger blocks can't contain variables or template expressions.

Currently, we need to hardcode the value of the triggers field.

I can fully understand your requirement.It would be convenient if we could change the whole pipeline Yaml file based on variables.

You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.